# How to get Collection of Chart Elements in Word using VBA?

Tags: vba, charts, ms-word

In MS Word 2010, the list/collection of chart elements for a selected chart can be seen as follows:

1. Select a chart.
2. In the Format Tab, select the dropdown menu button (just above Format Selection). This dropdown lists all the Chart Elements for the selected chart.

I want to use this list of Chart Elements in a program. Is there any way I can retrieve this list programatically(preferably using Word VBA) ?

Comment: They represent different [properties of the `Chart` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822690%28v=office.14%29.aspx). I doubt there is a need to generate this list dynamically - if you do, how will you know what can be done with each element? Just hardcode the list.

Comment: Yes, they represent different properties of Chart class. But, not all properties are applicable to all Chart Types. That List in the Format tab, correctly gives the applicable chart elements pertaining to a chart type.

Answer (score 0):

Short of possibly using the Windows API or the Ribbon Accessibility API there's no way to get the content of this list from the Ribbon.

The Office APIs don't provide this information, directly. You'd pretty much have to query all the possible elements, such as HasTitle, to build your own list.

It might be more efficient to extract the WordOpenXML from the document, get the chart "package" from the OPC flat file (XML string) and analyze its elements.